# Migrate WordPress users (with passwords) to DotNetNuke

Tags: wordpress, dotnetnuke

We are thinking about moving a site from WordPress to DNN.  The WP site has 81 users and I'm wondering if I can avoid having them create new passwords when the DNN site goes live.  I don't know what plug-in (or if I need one) I'll be using for DNN user management yet (I'm new to DNN).  I know the WP site is just using the built-in user list, with the "Members Only" plugin to require log-in.

I imagine I can get access to whatever format WP saves the passwords as... but is this likely to be the same hash algorithm that DNN (or a popular plugin) would use, and do I have easy access to any salt used?

It isn't too hard for users to reset their passwords, and is good practice for them to change them from time to time anyway... Mostly, if it is easy for me to avoid it, then I would like to try.  If not a simple process, not going to bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless you the details on how wp hashes the password...you will probably need to know the encryption method (md5,sha etc) and the salt. it shouldn't be difficult once you know those 2 variables, i think.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm hoping someone already knows the 2 methods that WP and DNN use, so can tell me if it will work or not, and about how much work it will be.  Seems like something that a lot of people must have done already... moved from WP to DNN (and visa-verse).

Comment: wp uses phpass, pretty sure dnn doesnt. you could always use phpass for dnn, then you dont need to think/code that much (i'm just lazy). wp uses `wp_hash_password()` function in `wp-icludes/pluggable.php`. hashpass object is hardcoded with `new PasswordHash(8, true)` (in my fresh wp 3.6.1 install). maybe for best support for dnn, do it dnn way, then if you have issues later about passwords in dnn, you can get dnn community help. of course that comes at a user annoyance cost.